# Would Zirconium (IV) Silicate be stable in a hot oxygen atmosphere?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

As per the title, really. I potentially need to protect a bit of pipework from hot oxygen (800-1000 K), and I've seen this refractory paint for sale. It says it's good up to 1750 C, but hot oxygen is another kettle of fish. I'd have thought since it's formed from oxides at high temperature and it doesn't lose any oxygen in the process that it'd be fine? Just thought I'd check with the experts here before burning a hole in my kit!

Comment: In addition to asking here, you should also contact the manufacturer.  They should be the best experts on their own product.

Comment: Zirconium only goes to +4 oxidation state so it can't get oxidised any further which is a plus. Zirconium silicate is used as an enamel and glaze so clearly high temps are not a problem. All sounds promising but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Yeah, I've contacted them too. Just thought I'd ask here as well to see if anyone had a technical reason why it wouldn't work, rather than the typical manufacturer answer of "we haven't tested that scenario".